# Change over to 'Create new wallet from hardware' after install

Tags: wallet, hardware

I installed the Monero GUI on Linux (Mint) just using the 'Create new wallet' option, but I made a mistake and now I need to switch it to 'Create new wallet from hardware'. How can I do that? Do I have to uninstall then reinstall it?

Comment: You can simply close the current wallet on the `Settings` page and redo the process.

Comment: That seems to have worked. Now, if I were to do a transaction on one machine, like my PC, and then later open of the wallet on Linux, will that transaction still show up? Or will it only be readable on the machine where it was first execute?

Comment: You can replicate the wallet on a different system. I've linked a guide.

Comment: Great. I'll take a look at the link.